# why are these words not formulas?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

these words here : 
A^B

( A implies B v C )

( A implies B,c )

( A^B^C)

for all A ( A v not A )

(( A^(B implies C )) v ( not A implies ( B^C)) ^ ( not A v B ))

not (A)

why these words are not formulus ?!!

the text don't give the reason !

and in other hand , it says 
A

( A implies (B is equivlant to A ))

( not A implies A )

not (A implies A )

((( A^ ( not B implies not A )) ^ ( not B v not C )) implies ( c implies not A )

are formulas

why the first are not and the second are ?!

Comment: You might want to provide some context (eg, this is from text book X, when discussing topic Y,...).

Comment: @gnometorule , it's from text " mathematical logic : a course with exercises  , Part 1 " in page 10 , chapter 1 section 1

Comment: the topic is " syntax and propositional formulas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented knowing the text will probably help.

That said, something like "A $\lor$ B" is NOT a formula, while "(A $\lor$ B)" is a formula, because of problems that could arise were A $\lor$ B a formula.  In logic, the rule of replacement has unrestricted applicability.  That means that if we have *any* two logically equivalent expressions C and D, we can mechanically replace one instance of C, wherever it appears in any expression, by D and the truth value of the expression does not change.  If A $\lor$ B is a formula this is NOT necessarily the case, as can demonstrated as follows:

Let 1 stand for truth, and 0 for falsity.  From 0$\lor$0=0 we can derive 1$\land$(0$\lor$0)=1$\land$0=0, and since it is true that 1=1$\lor$0, it would also come as valid to derive that 1$\land$(0$\lor$0)=1$\lor$0$\land$(0$\lor$0)=1$\lor$(0$\land$(0$\lor$0))=1$\lor$0=1.  Thus, we can change the truth value of 1$\land$(0$\lor$0) via replacement, given a$\lor$b as a formula in general.

Given that only expressions with parentheses around them come as formulas, the above problem does not arise, since one can only substitute a parenthesized formula for a truth value, which makes it unambiguous as to how one calculates or would calculate a formula.  Thus, in infix notation full parentheses always come as required for writing formulas.  In prefix (Polish) and postfix (reverse Polish) notations parentheses are NOT necessary in the same way for writing formulas.

Comment: when i was reading the definition of heifht , there was a sympol which I don't know  , if F , G are two formulas , h[f] is the height of the formula f ,then  h[ G a F ] is less or equal to sup( h[F] , h[G] ) + 1 
a is one of the connectives , my question is , what is sup ???

Comment: "sup" usually refers to supremum: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supremum

Answer (score 1):

The text probably has a specific definition of a formula which you are being asked to check.  Just guessing, but A implies B v C may fail because it is missing parentheses.  The text may define a sentence is a capital letter, or (B v C), or (A implies K) or such.  The parentheses are needed for unambiguous readability.  Later it may allow you to eliminate the parentheses using priority, but often the formal definition of a sentence includes them.  The second may fail for the comma or for the lower case c.

Comment: he defined the formulas as follows : 
formulas are thus words formed with the following alphabet : 
S = P U { not , or , and , implies , is equivlant to } U { ), (}

Comment: but what is wrong with :
(( A^(B implies C )) v ( not A implies ( B^C)) ^ ( not A v B ))

Comment: @MathsLover:  your first comment gives the alphabet, but not the allowed syntax.  The quote you give does not allow v or ^, but it looks like they are allowed.  For the second, there are probably supposed to be parentheses around not A, but again I am guessing.  Otherwise, how do you tell (not A) v B from not (A v B)?

Comment: I think I understood this point :) 

what do you mean by "  how do you tell (not A) v B from not (A v B)? " ??

Comment: @MathsLover: In the first only A is negated and the sentence is true if A is false or B is true.  In the second the whole disjunction is negated, so the sentence is only true if both A and B are false.  That is why the parentheses are important.